# Error installing app in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am creating a android app where i am using sync adapters and Firesbase Messaging Service. At a point everything worked fine and then suddenly now whenever i am trying to install my app on a device, it gives me a message "Installation Cancelled By User" and ERROR Installing app. I have tried doing every possible thing.

1. I changed my package name from com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech to com.example.raghav.aurinkoinfotech (Uppercase to lowercase), but that didn't work out.
2. I tried the option ("invalidate caches/Restart") in file menu of android studio.

Please help me.

Following is my manifest file......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>


<application
    android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Global"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.EditProfile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">


    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">




    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">



    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.GalleryUtil"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">


    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.ProjectOptions"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">




    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Project_Operations"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">


    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.ChatActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">


    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.ManageTeam"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">


    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Project_options_recyclerviews"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme1">


    </activity>



    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Discussion"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">


    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Project_tasks"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">




    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Checklist"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Labels"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.TeamMembers"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.Calender"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme1">

    </activity>


    <provider
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.StubProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true"/>


    <service android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.fcmInstanceIdService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"> </action>

        </intent-filter>

    </service>



    <service android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.FcmMessagingService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"> </action>

        </intent-filter>

    </service>


    <service
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.AuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.raghav.AurinkoInfotech.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process="sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: just disable the developer option in phone and enable it again, and make sure that application from unknown source should be accepted in setting

Comment: If you are testing in xiaomi devices, then might have to allow the app from the phone settings "Security". This could happen if you deny the app install once for you app. In this case all you would have to do is enable/allow the app in Security settings.

Comment: @Akhil Soman - I am using 2 devices Xiaomi mi4 and Intex Aqua Ring and i am using these two devices from past 6-8 months. I know the settings for these devices but still i checked it again and everything looks fine there.

Comment: @Rahul - I did what you suggested. I disabled the developer option and enabled it again but its still not working. Till yesterday afternoon it was working fine. Suddenly this thing started and i have tried lot many options to get it right. I also tried disabling the "instant Run" but still not getting it fixed.

Comment: Also i would like to tell you that i took the apk and transferred it to my device through file transfers USB and tried installing it. It says "There was a problem while parsing the package".... Just told you if it can get you at something.

Comment: what is your phone model ?

Comment: Did you change the package name in manifest only.? I mean when you renamed the package name, did you refracted the folder structue name too. If not then that could be the reason for "There was a problem while parsing the package" error.

Comment: @Rahul- no i changed my package name by right clicking on my package and then Refactor and rename package. Where ever my package name is used it got changed.

Comment: my phone model is Xiaomi mi4  and Intex Aqua ring. But i have been testing this same application on both the phones for past 6-8 months, at that time it was working fine. i don't think there is any problem with the model or device